# Can't boot linux besides Ubuntu

Tags: linux

I wanted to switch to Linux, but the only distro so far I could even boot from a live USB was Ubuntu.

I tried Xubuntu, Manjaro, Linux Mint, Elementary OS and none could boot, though when I tried booting them on my old laptop, everything went fine.

The laptop I use is a Lenovo Y500 and I did try disabling secure boot but nothing worked. So is there a way to fix this or do I have to use Ubuntu?

Comment: What error(s) were you getting when trying to boot the other distributions or how did you know they weren't working?

What happened when you turned secure boot off, "nothing worked" isn't very descriptive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try disabling UEFI? A lot of times it's called "Legacy Boot" but some distros have a hard time with UEFI still.

If you get ubuntu to install you can turn it into xubuntu with the commands

sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop*

sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop